What are the ideals of $n\mathbb{Z}$?
I know how to find the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. However, now I am trying to find the ideals of $n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$. Using the same ideas about $\mathbb{Z}$, I have there questions:

Is it correct to say that all ideals of $n\mathbb{Z}$ are principal ideals of the form $(mn)$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$?.

Also, are all prime/maximal ideals of $n\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $(pn)$, where $p$ is a prime.

Finally, I know that $4\mathbb{Z}$ is a maximal ideal of $2\mathbb{Z}$. But, is it also a prime ideal?


Please tell me if this is right or did I make a mistake.

Isn't ${2}\cup4\mathbb Z$ an ideal of $2\mathbb Z$?

@KentaS:  that’s not closed under addition, e.g., it doesn’t contain  $2+4$

See this duplicate for $n=2$. It easily works for all $n$.

@J.W.Tanner ah right, so an ideal must be a sub-abelian group of $n\mathbb Z$, which must be of the form $mn\mathbb Z$ (so being closed under multiplication by $n\mathbb Z$ is actually unnecessary to prove 1).

@KentaS Exactly. The same words are used in the duplicate (first sentence of the answer).

Any non-trivial additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z,$ and hence principal.

@ThomasAndrews, what about maximal and prime ideals?
